# How to use the inbuilt FindAllPathsOfLengthN() methods in rdkit..?

Tags: python, rdkit

I recently came across a inbuilt method in rdkit called : FindAllPathsOfLengthN

i tried to find path length of 2 in a caffine molecule.

below is the code i executed... but it produced **has no attribute** error

please help.

```
      mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles("CN1C=NC2=C1C(=O)N(C)C(=O)N2C") 
      mol

      rdkit.findAllPathsOfLengthN(mol,2)
```

expected a list of paths of length 2.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys i found the answer...

I just needed to import a submodule and use the method.

```
  import rdkit

  from rdkit.Chem import rdmolops

  mol=Chem.MolFromSmiles("c1occ(NC(F)(F)F)c1N(O)C")
  mol

  print(len(list(rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.FindAllPathsOfLengthN(mol,2))))

  print(len(list(rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.FindAllPathsOfLengthN(mol,3))))

  print(len(list(rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.FindAllPathsOfLengthN(mol,1))))
```

output :

```
 19
 19
 13
```